# How can I solve this bug in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

i want to run an r shiny app using the typical command `runApp()`. I made sure that i am in the correct working directory and that the shiny package is loaded. when running the app, i get this error message here:

````
Error in p(class = "text-right", textOutput(outputId = "callsCount")) : 
unused argument (class = "text-right")``` 

What can i do to solve that error ?

Thanks
````

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I got at reproducing your error:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  uiOutput(outputId = "myUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p <- reactive(3)

  output$myUI <- renderUI({
    p(class = "text-right", textOutput(outputId = "callsCount"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
Warning: Error in p: unused arguments (class = "text-right", textOutput(outputId = "callsCount"))
```

There are two fixes you need to make:

**fix1:**

It seems you have a reactive expression named `p`. Change it's name to something else. An alternative is to specify explicitly from which environment shiny should get the function `p()`:

```r
output$myUI <- renderUI({
    shiny::p(class = "text-right", textOutput(outputId = "callsCount"))
  })
```

**fix2:**

Replace `textOutput(outputId = "callsCount")` with the text you want to render.
For example:

```r
output$myUI <- renderUI({
    shiny::p(class = "text-right", "This is the text to render")
  })
```

**final ui and server:**

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  uiOutput(outputId = "myUI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p <- reactive(3)

  output$myUI <- renderUI({
    shiny::p(class = "text-right", "This is the text to render")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```